# CLLocationmanger - decimal points for lat and long

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager

To find my phone's lat and long (current location) - i am using CLLocationmanager.
Whenever I try to fetch the location the decimal points are up to 6 values, like 10.007841 and 76.147856.
How can I make it is 8 decimal points.

I have given -

```
     self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is that when you print them out, you see 6 values. This is a property of "printf" formatting - the default is 6. The actual location information is stored as a double. So if you print out the number as:

```
NSLog(@"location %.8lf", location.latitude);
```

you will get 8 digits.

Comment: Side note: You can print both float and double values just with "%f", the "l" modifier has no effect here.

Comment: @MartinR, well, you are strictly correct - but the "lf" reminds the reader that the variable being printed is a double - its just emphasizes the point. [In case anyone does not know, floats arguments are promoted to doubles, and printf style formatters translate "%f" to %lf" internally now.